# Eclipse disable warning for automatic source generation folder

Tags: eclipse, maven, jaxb, warnings, compiler-warnings

I use JAXB and Maven to generate java files from xsd. Works nicely, but my project has warnings because the generate source code doesn't life up to the code style exspectations.

What is the easiest way to disable warnings for these gernerated source files that are placed in a seperate source folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Eclipse 4.2 this is built in and warnings can be turned off on a on folder basis.

For older versions: I used Maven to add ingore warning annotations to every file, but this was quite ugly and needed manual refresh to be visible in Eclipse.